# Form with a button that create an URL from a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am having troubles doing a simple form in html, for my forum.
I have a textbox and a button.
The textbox contains a nickname.
I need to redirect the user to a website that contains the URL website + the nickname (for example http://www.heythere/nick/textboxnickname).
The problem is that, with the code i wrote, my forum redirect me to it again, by adding to the url the names of my textbox and my button.

```
//Script
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function levaSpazi() 
  { 
   var i=0; 
   var gt = document.getElementById("gt"); 
   var strLength = gt.length; 

   for(i; i<strlength; i++){ 
    gt = gt.replace(" ","%20"); 
   } 

   var indirizzo="http://xboxdvr.com/gamer/" + gt; 
   window.location*.href=indirizzo; 

   return false; 
  } 
</script> 


//HTML
<form name="Guarda" onSubmit="return levaSpazi();">
...
<input type="text" maxlength="15" name="gt" id="gt"> 
<input type="submit" name="guarda" value="Guarda">
...
</form>
```

When i save this code, the platform which i'm using (forumfree.it), modifies "window.location.href" with "window.location*.href"

Comment: Where is your code? Show us what you tried.

Comment: i updated with the code (sorry i'm new here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A code snippet would be nice to see. The redirection might happend, because you set the wrong `type`. You should set it to `type="button"`.

Actually, you don't really need a form. Here is one example:

```
function openURL()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('myName').value;
    var url = 'http://www.heythere/nick/' + encodeURIComponent(name);

    // In current window
    window.location.href = url;

    // In new window
    window.open(url);
}
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="openURL()" value="Go"/>
```

But maybe I got you wrong. If you want to change the URL of the `action` attribute of your form (before it sends it), I guess this might work:

HTML:

```
<form data-url="http://www.heythere/nick/" action="" onsubmit="changeForm(event, this)">...</form>
```

JS:

```
function changeForm(e, formRef)
{
    // Prevent browser sending the form self
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById('myName').value;
    formRef.action = formRef.getAttribute('data-url') + encodeURIComponent(name);

    // Send
    formRef.submit();
}
```

I'm sending this from my phone and couldn't test it, sorry. But it should work like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript who serve submitting the form, an in JS add nickname to the url and redirect it.

But we don´t know what you use (simple HTML and PHP, ASP.NET or any Framework ?)

With JQuery:

```
$("your_form_selector").submit(function(){
    // var nickname = GetNickname
    $(this).attr("action", "your_new_url/" + nickname);
});
```

Comment: How is it done without jQuery? Can't load a library just to submit a form.

Comment: Please, look on *StanE* Comment when use only Javasript

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener to your button and pass a callback that concatenates your url with your textbox value on click event:

```js
var nickname = document.getElementById("txt");
function redirect () {
  window.location.href = "https://heythere.com/nick/" + nickname.value;
};
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', redirect);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" />
```